# how to add items to datagridviewcombobox from database vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcombobox

hi  i have dgv1 and dgv2 after cellMouseClick on dgv2 it fill DGV1 by  selected row, how can add items from database to  DataGridViewComboBox in dgv1 
i try this code but nothing happen

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As  DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellMouseClick

    Dim indx As Integer = DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index

Dim y, z, k, v As String

    Dim x, h, n As Long

    Dim t As Integer = 1

    x = DataGridView2(0, indx).Value.ToString()

    y = DataGridView2(1, indx).Value.ToString()

    z = DataGridView2(2, indx).Value.ToString()

    h = DataGridView2(3, indx).Value.ToString()

    n = DataGridView2(4, indx).Value.ToString()

    v = DataGridView2(5, indx).Value.ToString()

    k = DataGridView2(6, indx).Value.ToString()

     Dim ss = CType(DataGridView1.Columns(2), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)

        ss.DataSource = dataset1

        ss.ValueMember = "UnitNum"

        ss.DisplayMember = "UnitName"

        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(x, y, ss, t, h, h * t, v)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` or a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` or a `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl` in the same way as you treat a regular `ComboBox` control, which means that you can either `Add` to its `Items` collection directly or you can bind data via the `DataSource` property and set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.  If you set the properties on the column then they get automatically propagated to cells in that column and if you set them on cell then they get propagated to the editing control in that cell.

Comment: any example to fill   DataGridViewComboBox  from data base ? treat  like a regular ComboBox is not working